# How can I solve a problem with my Android Studio emulator?

Tags: android-studio

I have a problem with Android Studio. Here is the photo I created on the machine; when I run it, my screen is not displayed in full screen.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a misconfigured emulator.

Answer (score 2):

Follow this step.May be it's help for you.

```
01. Remove this emulator.
02. Create new emulator.
03. C:\Users\*user*\.gradle\caches file delete. 
04. Restart your android studio.
```